# Distribution of the product of a Normal and an Exponential random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, products

What is the probability distribution of $M$, given $M=V*X/k$, where $X$ is Normal, $V$ is Exponential, $k$ constant?

Or, in the real world, the probability distribution of (Cost/k) where Cost=Price*Quantity, price Normal, quantity Exponential and k constant.

The distribution of estimated quantity (the actual quantity is unknown) will be the empirical distribution of Cost spread out (extended or shrunk) by different levels of $k$?

WolframAlpha (Mathematica) and MathWay both seem strangely obdurately in misunderstanding this elementary question, in every formulation....

Comment: General Normal $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ or standard Normal $N(0,1)$? Standard Exponential or with parameter $\lambda$. And if the latter, what formulation? And what makes you think it is elementary?

Comment: On further reflection, your question needs further assumptions. In particular, the basis of almost any economic model is that quantity $Q= Q(P, ...)$ i.e. quantity is a function of price. If so, then your Price and Quantity random variables are _not_ independent. ...... Or, perhaps more correctly, you may wish to re-model this as a SINGLE random variable price $P$, where $Q = Q(P, blah)$ and you seek the distribution of total cost (or revenue).