# Product distribution of independent Normal and Exponential random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution

Let $Z = XY$ be a random variable which is the product of two independent random variables $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and $Y\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$. I'm wondering, is there some way to write the expression for the PDF of $Z$? (Side note: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302552/distribution-of-the-product-of-a-normal-and-an-exponential-random-variable) is very similar, but didn't get an answer)

Based on the standard definition of the product of two independent random variables, the PDF of $Z$, $f_Z(z)$, can be written as:

\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}f_Y(x)f_X(z/x)\frac{1}{x}dx\\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda\exp(-\lambda x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\Big(\frac{-z^2}{2\sigma^2x^2}\Big)\frac{1}{x}dx
\end{align}

I'm not too sure how to go about simplifying this. Any ideas? Approximations?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be expressed in an elementary way.  Maple evaluates the integral as
$$  \frac{1}{\pi z} G^{3, 0}_{0, 3}\left({\frac {{z}^{2}{\lambda}^{2}}{{8\sigma}^{2}}}\, \Big\vert\,^{}_{1, 1/2, 1/2}\right)$$
where $G$ is the Meijer G function.