# Analytical solution of Product of Normal distribution and Exponential Distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, analytic-geometry, exponential-distribution

Numerically (Monte Carlo) we can get the distribution of the **product of normal distribution and Exponential distribution** (Both are independent). Could we do analytically?

This question is linked with [Meijer G function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2892627/product-distribution-of-independent-normal-and-exponential-random-variables), but still not yet calculated

Comment: try doing it via MGFs and see what you come up with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal distribution is $f_N(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$. The exponential distribution has probability distribution function $f_E(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\geq 0$ and $f_E(x)=0$ for $x<0$.

The probability distribution function $f(z)$ for the [product distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution) is given by the integral $f(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_N(x)f_E(\frac{z}{x})\frac{1}{|x|}\mathrm{d}x$.

This comes out as $f(z)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\lambda}{x\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{\lambda z}{x}}$.

Wolfram Alpha could not find an analytic solution so I doubt that an analytic solution exists.

Comment: This is $kE[1/|X|]$ for a particular normal distribution, whether that helps at all is totally fair game